# Java Spring ManyToOne how to load only reference

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, many-to-many

I have data being persisted in Spring of employees and "personal development plans". Employee is the dominant class, so to speak. It looks like this:

```
@Entity(name = "employee")
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
    private int id;

    // etc...
}
```

Personal Development Plan looks like this:

```
@Entity(name = "pdp")
@Table(name = "PDP")
public class PersonalDevelopmentPlan implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "PDP_ID")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
    private Employee employee;

    // etc..
}
```

In the database it is stored as a foreign key reference from `PDP -> Employee`.

I want to be able to load a PDP as it is in the database, with only employee id, but i always get the whole Employee object with all attributes. How do i do this?

I tried `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.Lazy)` but this gives me the following error when fetching:

> Type definition error: [simple type, class
>   org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor]; nested
>   exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No
>   serializer found for class
>   org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no
>   properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception,
>   disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference
>   chain:
>   java.util.ArrayList[0]->nl.kars.lms.model.pdp.PersonalDevelopmentPlan["employee"]->nl.kars.lms.model.Employee$HibernateProxy$AAwzPX4I["hibernateLazyInitializer"])

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: can you try implementing the Serializable interface in the Employee class.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only the ID, why not map it without the relationship ?

```
@Entity(name = "pdp")
@Table(name = "PDP")
public class PersonalDevelopmentPlan implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "PDP_ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
    private Long employeeId;

    // etc..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is actually how an ORM works... mapping table(relational side) to entities(object side). And mapping between entities is not done via ids but by entity references. 
So either just persist the id (so remove strong relation) or use a projection query to just get back the employee Id.

Answer (score 0):

You can create getter:

```
public Long getEmployeeId(){
 return this.employee.getId();
}
```

Or you can change mapping to value `private Long employeeId`.